# Make Container take content size of child

Tags: flutter, stack, containers, size

I'm new in Flutter,

I have a Container which child is Stack that using Positioned inside.
My problem is Container just taking Non-Positioned widget size.
Here is my problem:
[image]

I want something like this:

[image]

Here is my Widget code:

```dart
class CheckUpItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const CheckUpItem({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: 100,
      child: Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
          color: Colors.white,
          border: Border.fromBorderSide(
            BorderSide(
              width: 1,
              color: Color(0xFFBAD9F8),
            ),
          ),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Color(0x00000029),
              offset: Offset(2, 3),
              blurRadius: 2,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(4),
                topRight: Radius.circular(4),
              ),
              child: Container(
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color(0xFFE6F6FF),
                  border: Border(
                    bottom: BorderSide(
                      width: 1,
                      color: Color(0xFFBAD9F8),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                child: Consumer(
                  builder: (context, ref, child) {
                    return Center(
                      child: Text(
                        'BMI',
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 14,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          height: 1.43,
                          color: Color(0xFF6B6B6B),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.5, bottom: 4),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Stack(
                    clipBehavior: Clip.none,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        width: 36,
                        height: 36,
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          border: Border.fromBorderSide(
                            BorderSide(
                              width: 2,
                              color: Color(0xFFBF3D3D),
                            ),
                          ),
                          color: Color(0xFFF86060),
                        ),
                        child: const Center(
                          child: Text(
                            'B',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              height: 1,
                              fontSize: 20,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Positioned(
                        bottom: -6,
                        left: 26,
                        child: Container(
                          width: 22,
                          height: 22,
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(1, 0, 3, 2),
                          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                            border: Border.fromBorderSide(
                              BorderSide(
                                width: 1,
                                color: Color(0xFF6A8FD4),
                              ),
                            ),
                            color: Color(0xFFE0EEFC),
                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          ),
                          child: SvgPicture.asset(ImageAssets.speaker),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 6),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I'm stucking all day with this, I'm tempary using Column and `const SizedBox(height: 6)` for fake height.

How to make it right way?

P/s: Sorry, my English is not good!

Comment: I can't regenerate your issue, with code you provide, everything works fine.

Comment: because I'm using Column with SizedBox for making fake height, Can you remove last ` const SizedBox(height: 6),` and its Column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because every thing is static hear and you know how much the svg container going down, you can calculate it and add it to padding bottom, like this:

```
Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.5, bottom: 10), // 4 + 6(Positioned bottom)
                      child: Stack(
                        clipBehavior: Clip.none,
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            width: 36,
                            height: 36,
                            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                              shape: BoxShape.circle,
                              border: Border.fromBorderSide(
                                BorderSide(
                                  width: 2,
                                  color: Color(0xFFBF3D3D),
                                ),
                              ),
                              color: Color(0xFFF86060),
                            ),
                            child: const Center(
                              child: Text(
                                'B',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  height: 1,
                                  fontSize: 20,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Positioned(
                            bottom: -6,
                            left: 26,
                            child: Container(
                              height: 22,
                              width: 22,
                              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                border: Border.fromBorderSide(
                                  BorderSide(
                                    width: 1,
                                    color: Color(0xFF6A8FD4),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                color: Color(0xFFE0EEFC),
                                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                              ),
                              child: SvgPicture.asset(
                                'assets/images/tes.svg',
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But, if I have non-static children like Positioned with dynamic child inside, how can Container size growing with these Positioned child?

Comment: Stack widget grow as much as its biggest child, so as long as you are using Positioned you have to do this.